# Android Studio - Firebase JAVA - Realtime Database (get value from DB and check if)

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm studying Android Studio and Firebase to a do simple app. And is almost working.
How can I grab data from firebase and store it in one Variable to check user level?

```
"Users" : {
"S7TEROObjae8RfsMEbmylTmiJqS2" : {
  "email" : "testd@test.com",
  "fullName" : "doug",
  "ident" : "associado"
}
```

So if the user has  Value Ident = "associado" should be followed to AssociadoActivity.
Right now everyone is sent to AdminActivity.

```
   mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                if(user.isEmailVerified()) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminActivity.class));
                } else {
                    user.sendEmailVerification();
                }
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "O login não pode ser efetuado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this article to get data from firebase
[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

then just save your data in local storage like [Preferencemanager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager)

then open your activity according to your condition